# Is Isolated Storage Always Necessary?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I see alot of examples on how to write data from an app to a file then put it in isolated storage. I do not want to write any data to my xml file, I just simply want to save it into isolated storage then query it later.

A few simple questions

- Someone have code on how to put an existing xml file into isolated storage. Also since I am not writing to this file, do I need isolated storage still? Can I just add the xml to my project and use Linq to xml to open it query it and close it on a button click?
- I wanna query the xml through my application in the background. I see alot of examples on serializing, do I need to do this? Can I just open the xml file and use linq to xml to query the data?

Can I just do this, set bbxml.xml to Content and forget about isolated storage and just do this?

```
 using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("bbxml.xml"))
        {
            XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(reader);
            //query xml....
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Include the XML file in your project files in Visual Studio, then in the Properties window make sure `Build Action` is set to `Content` and `Copy to Output Directory` is set to `Copy always` or `Copy if newer`. This will include the file in the output XAP file.

To access this file in code use:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load( "path/to/my/file.xml" );
```

Of course, it doesn't have to be `XDocument`, you can use any XML reader class similarly.

Comment: If you can do it this way, why the need for isolated storage?

Comment: @Nick LaMarca: A file included this way cannot be modified by your app, but files stored in isolated storage are modifiable.

Comment: So, since I am not modifying the file this is the best way to do it? ....And thank you for your clarification

Comment: @Nick LaMarca: Yes, if the file does not need to be modified, I would just include it in the XAP.

Comment: @Praetorian I'm doing exactly this the only change is that I'm using TEXT File. I did everything you wrote here but when I tries to read from Text File it gives the following error "Attempt to access the method failed: System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(System.String)"

Comment: my sample code:  

string AllLines = new StreamReader("Foo.txt").ReadToEnd();

Comment: @KhanZeeshan: I've never tried to read a text file but I have read XML files using the code above. Try playing with the path you call StreamReader with. Also, make sure there is no leading `/`. If that fails maybe you can use an XML file instead of text?

Comment: I found out that "Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Foo.txt", UriKind.Relative))" works perfectly for my scenario.

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured it out. You should post this to the question you asked.