# do we need to manually add xml to our solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

i am writing a simple wp7 application that uses isolated storage concept. i could successfully complete the app but while trying to test if it works properly, i am getting an error stating "abc.xml" file is missing in the zap. 
abc.xml is created using the code:

```
using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
  using (var fs = store.OpenFile("abc.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
  {
    var root = new XElement("User");
    var Mobile_Number = new XElement("Mobile_NUmber", txtMobNum.Text);

    var Sec_Ques = new XElement("Sec_Ques", secQues);
    var xDoc = new XDocument();
    root.Add(Mobile_Number, Sec_Ques);
    xDoc.Add(root);
    xDoc.Save(fs);
    fs.Close();
  }                
}
```

if i add abc.xm to the solution, the err is cleared, but i do not think this is the right way to do. can someone help me out
thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665632/is-isolated-storage-always-necessary/5666947#5666947).

Answer (score 0):

Any file created in isolated storage on one run of your application isn't considered to be part of the application to be deployed to other devices, no.

If you have a file you want to ship with the application, you should include it explicitly in your project.

Comment: hey thanks for the answer but how an i get rid of the error? also getting one more run time err along with this: "OPERATION NOT PERMITTED ON ISOLATED STORAGE FILE STREAM"